# Spark steaming read from Kafka and apply Spark SQL aggregations in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Spark job that reads data from a database and applies *Spark SQL* aggregations. Code is as follows (omitting only conf options):

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    Dataset df = MongoSpark.read(sqlContext).options(readOptions).load();
    df.registerTempTable("data");
    df.cache();
    aggregators = sqlContext.sql(myQuery);
```

Now I want to create another job that reads messages from *Kafka* via *Spark streaming* and then applies the same aggregations via *Spark SQL*. My code so far is as follows:

```
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.99.100:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", KafkaStatisticsPayloadDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "Group1");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(topic);

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(topic).setMaster("local");

   /*
    * Spark streaming context
    */
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(2));
    /*
     * Create an input DStream for Receiving data from socket
     */
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, StatisticsRecord>> stream =
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    streamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, StatisticsRecord>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
            );
```

So far I have read and deserialized the messages successfully. So my question is how can I actually apply *Spark SQL* aggregations on them. I tried the following but it does not work. I think I somehow need to isolate first the "value" field which contains the actual message.

```
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(streamingContext.sparkContext());
    stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.rdd(), StatisticsRecord.class);
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("data");
        df.cache();
        Dataset aggregators = sqlContext.sql(SQLContextAggregations.ORDER_TYPE_DB);
        aggregators.show();
    });
```

Comment: Seen this? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html or https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem with the following code. Note that I now store the messages in JSON format instead of actual objects.

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(topic).setMaster("local");
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(2));

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(topic).getOrCreate();

    /*
     * Kafka conf
     */
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();

    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", dbUri);
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "Group4");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("Statistics");

    /*
     * Create an input DStream for Receiving data from socket
     */
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    streamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
            );
    /*
     * Keep only the actual message in JSON format
     */
    JavaDStream<String> recordStream = stream.flatMap(record -> Arrays.asList(record.value()).iterator());
    /*
     * Extract RDDs from stream and apply aggregation in each one
     */
    recordStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        if (rdd.count() > 0) {
            Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(rdd.rdd());
            df.createOrReplaceTempView("data");
            df.cache();

            Dataset aggregators = spark.sql(SQLContextAggregations.ORDER_TYPE_DB);
            aggregators.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call context inside the function that is applied to your stream.